# How to generate a predicate array of OR statements

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I am trying to use the Criteria API instead of constructing queries as JPQL Strings as the Criteria API seems much better suited for this. However, I am having a few problems understanding how to construct the two following statements.

```
SELECT e 
FROM Subject e 
WHERE e.company = :c1 
OR e.company = :c2 
OR e.company = :c3
```

In this case I need to iterate over an unknown number of values (c1, c2, c3 etc.) to match to the same attribute.

```
SELECT e 
FROM Subject e 
WHERE e.company 
LIKE :c1 
OR e.account 
LIKE :c1 
OR e.email 
LIKE :c1
```

In this case I need to pass in a single value (c1) and have a 'LIKE' comparison done on a specific range of attributes.

My current pattern looks something like this:

```
// Criteria
CriteriaBuilder builder = subjectDAO.criteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Subject> query = builder.createQuery(Subject.class);

// Root
Root<Subject> subject = query.from(Subject.class);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList();

for (String property : map.keySet()) {
    String value = (String) coreFilter.get(map);
    predicates.add(????? This is where I come unstuck ?????);
}

// pass all the predicates into the query
query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
```

NB. I don't have any problems constructing the Query object or specifying the Root or Joins. I am just having problems with the specificity of the above queries. For the sake of clarity just assume that all the attributes are String and don't require any joins.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The expression [`CriteriaQuery<T> where(Predicate... restrictions)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#where%28javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...%29), as you can see in the javadoc,

> Modify the query to restrict the query result according to the conjunction of the specified restriction predicates.

So, it makes the conjunction of the predicates in the list, i.e. it concatenates them with `AND` expressions. In order to concatenate them with `OR` expression, simply use [`CriteriaBuilder#or(Predicate... restrictions)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#or%28javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...%29)

```
query.where(builder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {})));
```

Comment: What does '_[Create a disjunction (with zero disjuncts). A disjunction with zero disjuncts is false.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#disjunction%28%29)_' mean?

Comment: It means that if your map is empty, the final predicate will be false and your query will give no results

Comment: How is that different from `predicates.add(
                        builder.or(
                        builder.like(subject.get(Subject_.email), literal),
                        builder.like(contact.get(Contact_.firstName), literal),
                        builder.like(contact.get(Contact_.lastName)
                        );`

Comment: They are equivalent, you can try yourself (print the generated queries by adding some logging to the JPA provider's configuration). The difference is that in my way the number of conditions can vary dynamically, that is what you are asking if I didn't misunderstood your question.

Comment: Fantastic, so my basic restriction is that my Predicates will always be concatenated with AND. ie. When I pass my List<Predicate> into query.where(predicates). What I'm basically getting is query.where(predicate1 AND predicate2 AND predicate3 etc.).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35431/discussion-between-tarka-and-perissf)