# JPA: m=Multiple criterias using entity Manager (OR clause)

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I am using JPA's(Entity Manager) Criteria query to fetch results from database. I need to put 'OR' clause between the criterias.

My code is as below:

```
List<Predicate> criteraList = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
if(user.getEid() != null){
    criteraList.add(criteriaUserCountry.like((Expression) userList.get("userCountryPK").get("user").get("eid"), "%" + user.getEid() + "%" ));
}
if(user.getFirstName() != null) {
    criteraList.add(criteriaUserCountry.like((Expression) userList.get("userCountryPK").get("user").get("firstName"), "%" + user.getFirstName() + "%" ));
}
cq.where(criteraList.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
TypedQuery<UserCountry> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
```

In terms of sql query, the above code inserts 'AND' between different criterias. How can an 'OR' clause be achieved using Entity Manager's criteria.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a predicate array of OR statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226800/how-to-generate-a-predicate-array-of-or-statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`OR` predicate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#or%28javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...%29)

Note that since it has an overload with varargs, you can pass a `Predicate[]` to it.